# Find Next Sibling Element In DOM With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I find the next element in the current scope? For example, I want to find `div` element and after this the next one which is `p`?

If I use `document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].nextSibling` it returns `#text`. I want it to return `p` tag.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [**`nextElementSibling`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling). If you need to support older browsers, traverse `nextSibling` until you find an Element node.

Answer (score 3):

You want [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling).

```
document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].nextElementSibling
```

The reason you are getting `#text` is because `nextSibling` will return the next node in the `childNodes` list of the parent element. In this case it is whitespace (hence #text) because of the newline used between `</div>` and `<p>`.