# How to extract "nearest neighbor" text using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given HTML content like this:

```
<span class="type">First Name</span>
<span class="entity">Bob</span>

<span class="type">Company Name</span>
<span class="entity">Apple</span>

<span class="type">Phone</span>
<span class="entity">800.555.5555</span>
```

How can you extract `Apple`? -- i.e. the first entity class closest to a `type` that has `Company Name` as the value.

**EDIT:**

Without using jQuery

Comment: Please show what research you've done and any code you've tried. It feels like you're asking the volunteers who answer Stack Overflow questions to do your work for you, which is not nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Next Sibling Element In DOM With JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805944/find-next-sibling-element-in-dom-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all `.type` elements and then check if text is equal to `Company Name` and then get `nextElementSibling`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.type').forEach(el => {
  let text = el.textContent;

  if (text == 'Company Name') {
    el.nextElementSibling.style.color = 'red'
  }
})
```

```html
<span class="type">First Name</span>
<span class="entity">Bob</span>

<span class="type">Company Name</span>
<span class="entity">Apple</span>

<span class="type">Phone</span>
<span class="entity">800.555.5555</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get a type–entity map:

```
const mapping = Object.assign(...Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".type + .entity"), ({previousElementSibling: {textContent: type}, textContent: entity}) => ({[type]: entity})));

console.log(mapping); // { "First Name": "Bob", "Company Name": "Apple", Phone: "800.555.5555" }
console.log(mapping["Company Name"]); // "Apple"
```

This works by taking the `textContent` of each `.entity` that is preceded by a `.type` and take the `textContent` of their `previousElementSibling`s. The nested destructuring parameter renames the `textContent` of the `.type` nodes to `type` and the `textContent` of the `.entity` nodes to `entity`, in order to create a `{[type]: entity}` object for each pair of `<span>`s. Finally, the `Object.assign` merges all objects into one.

Comment: This is the most concise and complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by finding all the `.type` elements then looping through them and checking the [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to see if it [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) `.entity`

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.type')).forEach(el => {
  let next = el.nextElementSibling
  if(el.textContent == 'Company Name' && next.matches('.entity')) {
    console.log(next.textContent)
  }
})
```

```html
<span class="type">First Name</span>
<span class="entity">Bob</span>

<span class="type">Company Name</span>
<span class="entity">Apple</span>

<span class="type">Phone</span>
<span class="entity">800.555.5555</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a matching entity for a type, the following is a viable solution. The idea is to pre-fetch the elements and then loop over types, and if a match is found, get the corresponding entity from another collection and change its color.

```js
var types = document.querySelectorAll('.type');
var entities = document.querySelectorAll('.entity');

for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
  if (types[i].textContent === 'Company Name') {
    entities[i].style.color = 'Red';
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="type">First Name</span>
<span class="entity">Bob</span>

<span class="type">Company Name</span>
<span class="entity">Apple</span>

<span class="type">Phone</span>
<span class="entity">800.555.5555</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a function which will be filter the entity with type as key

```
 <span class="type">First Name</span>
    <span class="entity">Bob</span>

    <span class="type">Company Name</span>
    <span class="entity">Apple</span>

    <span class="type">Phone</span>
    <span class="entity">800.555.5555</span>

      <script>
        var filterData = function(type){
            var typeData  =  document.getElementsByClassName('type')
          for(i=0;i<typeData.length;i++){
            if(typeData[i].outerText == type ){
                var entity = typeData[i].nextSibling.nextElementSibling
                console.log(entity.outerText)
            }

          }
        }
        filterData("Company Name")

     </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

just use this :

```
document.querySelector("type").nextSibling;
```

Comment: This results in the node containing "Bob".

Comment: @HereticMonkey cuz he didn't mention in which event he wanted to do that. can be this.nextSibling; or whatever

Comment: But that's not what you have. You have `document`; that makes the context the document. Therefore `querySelector` will select the first element which matches the selector in document order. Actually, in this case it would match nothing since there are no `type` elements.

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [jQuery's .next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
and then just call

```
$('.type').next().text();
```

to get the text as string

Comment: _“Without using jQuery”_.

Comment: @Xufox I made my answer _before_ he edited the question.

Comment: @AdanSandoval You answered 4 minutes ago and the question was edited 9 minutes ago.

Comment: SO is async: arguing about a few minutes is stupid. Questions may be edited during the answering process. It doesn't matter.